# Redirect language-specific URL to correct path prefix

Tags: 7, uri, i18n-l10n

Drupal 7. I have a multi-language website. Let's call it website.com.

At admin/config/regional/language/configure/url I have selected "Path prefix" as the "Part of the URL that determines language".

My host is using nginx. The hosting company has configured the site so that when I go to my Spanish language url (let's call it sitio-web-en-español.com) the browser ends up at website.com.

What I would like it to do is end up at website.com/es so that the users have Spanish language immediately without having to use the language switcher.

My question: Can I do this within Drupal or do I need to get my hosting company to change their configuration?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution that worked for me.

In the end I came to the conclusion that it was easiest to do this at the domain hosting company end.

So in the account where my Spanish-language domain (sitio-web-en-español.com) is managed, I set up a redirect that goes to:

website.com/es

... and it seems to work fine.